# form not submitting again after returning false in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a small problem.

When the form is submitted and the form returns false it will not submit again.

For instance. if the user misses out their name it will return false and show a message stating to input their name.

But the user can not resubmit the form without refreshing the page which means all data is lost.

How do i go about stopping this?

Here is the html side:

```
<form action="javascript:parseResponse();" method="post" name="ajaxcontactform" id="ajaxcontactform">

                <div class="contacttextarea">
                    <input name="contactform" type="hidden" value="1" />

                    <fieldset>
                        <textarea name="comment" cols="5" rows="5" class="contacttextarea"onfocus="if (this.value == 'Please Leave A Message') {this.value = '';}">Please Leave A Message</textarea>
                    </fieldset>

                </div>

                <div class="contacttextboxes">

                    <fieldset>
                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="contacttextform" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Please Insert Your Name') {this.value = '';}"value="Please Insert Your Name">
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="contacttextform" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Please Insert Your Phone Number') {this.value = '';}"value="Please Insert Your Phone Number">
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="contacttextform" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Please Insert Your Email') {this.value = '';}"value="Please Insert Your Email">
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <input name="send" type="submit" class="contactformbutton" value="Send">
                    </fieldset>

                </div>

            </form>
```

Here is the jquery side

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//// Start Contact Form ////
    $('#ajaxcontactform').submit(function(){$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');});


    $('#ajaxcontactform').submit(

        function parseResponse() {

            var usersname = $("#name");
            var usersemail = $("#email");
            var usersphonenumber = $("#phone");
            var usersmessage = $("#comment");
            var url = "contact.php";

                var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
                var valid = emailReg.test(usersemail);

                if(!valid) {
                    $("#contactwarning").html('<p>Your email is not valid!</p>').slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
                    return false;
                }

              if (usersname.val() == "" || usersname.val() == "Please Insert Your Name") {                
                   $("#contactwarning").html('<p>Please Insert Your Name!</p>').slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
                   return false;                   
              }
              if (usersemail.val() == "" || usersemail.val() == "Please Insert Your Email") {
                   $("#contactwarning").html('<p>Please Insert Your Email!</p>').slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
                   return false;
              }
              if (usersphonenumber.val() == "" || usersphonenumber.val() == "Please Insert Your Phone Number") {
                   $("#contactwarning").html('<p>Please Insert Your Phone Number!</p>').slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
                   return false;
              }
              if (usersmessage.val() == "") {
                   $("#contactwarning").html('<p>You forgot to leave a message!</p>').slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
                   return false;
              }



                    $.post(url,{ usersname: usersname.val(), usersemail: usersemail.val(), usersphonenumber: usersphonenumber.val(), usersmessage: usersmessage.val() } , function(data) {
                        $('#contactajax').html(data);
                        $("#ajaxcontactform").fadeOut(100).delay(12000).fadeIn(3000);
                        $('#contactajax').fadeIn(3000).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                    });

          }

      );
//// End Contact Form ////

 });
```

Here is the php part:

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['contactform']) && $_REQUEST['contactform'] == 1){
    echo '<p>Success!</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Form could not be sent, please try again!</p>';
}
```

All is working apart from when an error is shown it will not resubmit.

Comment: Don't use inline scripts and code. and test it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing action attribute value of form with some URL instead of JavaScript method. Also have the parseResponse() method body directly executed in Form.submit() event.

Edit:

Add following line of code before `return false` in every `if` condition. It will do the trick.

```
 $('input[type=submit]', $("#ajaxcontactform")).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: It will work as you are calling the same method on form submit event. Even before all this, try enabling "submit" button as soon as we show error. That will do the trick

Comment: how do i enable the submit button again after returning false?

Comment: that did the trick, this is a lesson learnt. i am new to jquery and i thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks submit, it looks like you're disabling the submit button (to prevent double submissions, I assume).

When returning false, you're never re-enabling the submit button. You will need to make sure that the disabled attribute is removed from the submit button before returning false.

Comment: i have not intentionally disabled the submit button, how would i enable the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

you would want to return false in any case since you want to submit the form without reloading the page.
simply add return false after $.post(); to prevent the page reload

and if you want to disable the submit button after the submission, then do it in the call back function of $.post